# How to check in JavaScript if resource exists without having console errors?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to check if a resource exists without having console errors.

I tried:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'HEAD',
    url : myUrl,
    success : function(){},
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // business logic
    }
}).complete(function() {
    // business logic
});
```

It perfectly works but errors are tracked in console.

Comment: You can't make HTTP requests without the browser console knowing.

Comment: try out a return false;

Comment: @Ionsomeday: I'm open to alternative ways.

Comment: @The Dark Knight I tried but the error message pops out in console before the error handler function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax errors writing to console by code

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

the 8434 line in jquery-1.8.3

so you can override this code:

```
$(function () {

var xhr = null;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest;
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')) {
    xhr = window.ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

var send = xhr.prototype.send;
xhr.prototype.send = function (data) {
    try {
        //uncomment this line to write the error to console
        //send.call(this, data);

        //you can write custom error to console
        console.log('your error message');
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
};
});
```